# Use image as radio button in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, radio-button

How can I use local images as radio buttons in rails?

I guess it's possible with the collection_radio_buttons helper but how is it possible to integrate local images?

This snippet shows me radio buttons with the texts below:

```
    <%= f.collection_radio_buttons(:paket, [[1, 'One'] ,[2, 'Two'], [3, 'Three']], :first, :last) do |b| %>
      <%= b.label { b.radio_button + b.text } %>
    <% end %>
```

Do I have to replace **b.radio_button** with an **image_tag**?

Comment: check my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes instead of b.text you can use image_tag to show image instead of text

```
#I have image in app/assets/images   as One.png,Two.png and so on.

<%= f.collection_radio_buttons(:paket, [[1, 'One'] ,[2, 'Two'], [3, 'Three']], :first, :last) do |b| %>
  <%= b.label { b.radio_button + image_tag('/'+b.text+'.png') } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works but all radio buttons have the same image now. How can I get an individual image for each radio button?

Comment: app/assets/images

Comment: With which names??

Comment: sample1.png, sample2.png, sample3.png

Comment: Rename images to match label i.e One.png, Two.png. And so on.  I updated code check.

Comment: Great solution! Works fine.